# Setting path variable for apache user on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, apache, path, environment-variables

I can't add `/usr/local/bin` to the apache users `PATH` variable. The user doesn't have a `.profile`, I can't `su` to the user, I can't export to the `PATH` from php using `exec` and adding

`SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin`

To either the `http.conf` or the `.htaccess` file doesn't make a difference. I can't find the `envvars` file to change that but I suspect there's some other problem.

I have restarted apache, and indeed my server.

Comment: Please state what expected behavior you would like to observe and what behavior you instead observe.  Then, why do you assume that `/usr/local/bin` isn't part of the `$PATH` and why do you want to add it?

Comment: It's not part of the path because when I echo it out from php, it shows /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

I want to add it to it to execute commands using exec.

I would like to see any kind of change, and I can go from there.

Comment: Also, the path for normal users is different:
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
So it is specific to the apache user. I need to be able to call an application that uses other application, it wouldn't be feasible to edit the source to directly point to each one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up following what Alfe suggested in his answer, except rather than in the `/etc/init.d/httpd` file (which could be overwritten easily on update) I added to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`:

`export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `/etc/passwd` to see which login shell the apache user has (on EC2 Ubuntu instances it should be `/bin/sh` which is a link to `/bin/dash`).  Then have a look at the man page of that shell and find out which configuration files are read upon login.  (For `/bin/dash` that would be `.login` in the user's home directory.)  In those you should be able to extend your `$PATH` as you like.

EDIT:

Since you seem to have no login shell for that user:  Have a look at the `/etc/init.d/*` scripts which start the system services.  Apache will be one of them.  They are started as `root` and may change the current user (e. g. to the apache user).  In there you might be able to adjust the PATH as you like it.

Patching those scripts, however, is not considered typical configuration.  Updates might overwrite what ever you patch there.

Comment: The /etc/passwd for apache points to /sbin/nologin, so it hasn't got a shell (I don't think, I'm not a pro unix guy). I looked for that path and couldn't find anything

Comment: I see.  Probably the apache process is just started without logging on properly by just switching the current user.  In this case the process running as the apache user is the root of all evil and has to change the `$PATH` itself before or when spawning new child processes.

Comment: I added another approach in my answer.

Comment: I don't have apache it seems, I have httpd. However, there's nothing in there about the path or changing users

Comment: No but you can probably change it there since it gets inherited by the child program.

Comment: Which script in `/etc/init.d/` did you look at?

Comment: httpd, as you say tho, that doesn't seem like the place I should be doing it, as it will be overwritten on updates.
I also don't even know what what syntax I would use in this file without destroying my server

Comment: These scripts are simple shell scripts.  So extending your PATH variable in there should pose no problem.  Stays the problem with the updates which would overwrite your patch; but unless you find a way to tweak apache to change the PATH before running subprocesses and unless you find a way to live with the PATH the way it currently is (that's what I would propose anyway), I don't see another option.

Comment: So would I set that with $PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin?

Comment: Use `export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I've ended up putting that in /etc/sysconfig/httpd instead and that worked

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You've found a solution yourself?  Then give your own answer stating how you did that and accept it.  This will help other people with the same issue as yours find the answer (they probably won't read our comment-thread to the bottom).  In case you found my answer helpful, you can upvote it, even if it didn't solve the issue.  Alternatively you can also accept my answer and hope that other readers will in question read to the bottom of the thread ;-)